# background image doesn't show in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

For some reason, the background image doesn't show in dompdf no matter what I try.  I've put the direct url as well.  None of them worked.  Can someone with dompdf experience tell me what I need to do?

It's important to note that other images appear just fine.  It's only the bakground images that are causing issues.  Here is one of the background images:

```
body{
 font-size:15px;
 background:url(bg.jpg) repeat-x bottom left;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using DOMODF 0.5.1? It's probably having trouble parsing the background shorthand. You could try breaking up the generic background property into the specific properties:

```
background-image: url(bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: bottom left;
```

I also found that sometimes I had to supply a full URL (http://example.com/bg.jpg).

The handling of this property is a little buggy in that version of DOMPDF. You might consider upgrading to the 0.6.0 code base ([currently at beta 1](http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf/browse_thread/thread/918f647b1819370b)). It has a number of improvements over the previous release.

Comment: Following up (since this has gotten some activity). The background shorthand should be parsed correctly in the newer releases. There is a stable release of the 0.6.x branch ([v0.6.1](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.1)) and the follow-up ([v0.7.0](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.7.0-beta)) is in beta.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same issue, in my local XAMMP (windows) it worked as it should, but when moving to a live server background images didn't show up.

After looking for a solution without success, finally solved it.

This wasn't working:

```
body{ font-size:15px; background-image:url(<?php echo getcwd(); ?>/bg.jpg); background-repeat:repeat;}
```

This worked like a charm:

```
body{ font-size:15px; background-image:url(./bg.jpg); background-repeat:repeat; }
```

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [DOMPDF supports background images](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/css21.php#properties), so I have to assume that the filepath is wrong.

If you add `<img src="bg.jpg" alt="" />` does it work?

I've found in the last project I used DOMPDF I needed to point the image file to it on the filesystem (not a relative path to webroot), and I had to use a root path that ended up looking like this

```
<img src="<?php echo DOCROOT; ?>assets/images/bg.jpg" alt="" />
```

Where `DOCROOT` became `/users/me/public_html/`. To test it as plain HTML before I sent to DOMPDF, I did a `str_replace()` to change the `DOCROOT` to `/` (relative to my path).

Comment: direct img tags work fine.  it's only the background images that don't work.  the file path is correct because when I view the html, it works.  when I take that same exact html and render it through dompdf, it doesn't work

Comment: @Refiking That is what I was saying, I've had many times where I view the HTML and it is fine, but I need to change the path to the image once it needs to be rendered with DOMPDF to get it to work.

Comment: If that's the case, then why can I see the other images just fine, but can't see the background image if they have the same path?

Answer (score 1):

for some odd reason I had the same problem
dompdf ver 0.6.1

1. in the img tags the full local path was needed
2. as a background image the relative path worked only,
   but background-image set in the style tag didn't work

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In your config file, set `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE` to true.

Then in your page or style sheet, use the full path (i.e., "http://yoursite.com/images/imagename.png") in the src tag or the url() in the style sheet.